# Istio: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I'm following this:

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/

and stopped my Docker Desktop environment for a few days before resuming.

It was working fine then.

Now, however, if I go to http://localhost/productpage

I get:

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried and the latest reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435581:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

and in the ingress gateway logs:

```
[2022-09-05T15:34:54.095Z] "GET /productpage HTTP/1.1" 503 UF,URX upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_failure,TLS_error:_268435581:SSL_routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED} - "-" 0 218 54 - "192.168.65.3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "24749e04-f3c2-9606-9199-fb666f6a0b75" "localhost" "10.1.0.253:9080" outbound|9080||productpage.default.svc.cluster.local - 10.1.0.250:8080 192.168.65.3:63774 - -
```

I assume it's something to do with the certificate. I'm not aware of changing anything however and now completely stumped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, any resolution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer here because this is the first question in SO that matched my search. I had a similar issue, but not running in Docker but in Kubernetes itself. I ended having to explicitly add a LABEL to my DEPLOYMENT section in my helm values file.

Something like this:

```
deployment:
  type: "simple"
  primary:
    labels:
      sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
    image:
      - repository: XXXXXXX
        tag: latest
```